# Generating XML files From CSV files

Tags: python, csv

so i have this code which generates the following xml file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  -<Solution version="1.0">-<DrillHoles total_holes="238">
         -<description>
               -<hole hole_id="1">
                    <hole toe="5797.82" cost="102.12" collar="5720.443070.942642.19"/>
```

But for

`collar ="5720.443070.942642.19"`, its supposed to be

`collar = "5720.44, 3070.94, 2642.19"`

which is written in the csv file. I just don't know how to put a comma in between the points. Please help

Here is the code:

```
    import csv
    from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring
    from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

    root = Element('Solution')
    root.set('version','1.0')
    tree = ElementTree(root)

    head = SubElement(root, 'DrillHoles')
    head.set('total_holes', '238')

    description = SubElement(head,'description')


    with open ('1250_12.csv', 'r') as data:
         current_group = None
         reader = csv.reader(data)
         i = 0
         for row in reader:
             if i > 0:
                x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,cost = row
                if current_group is None or i != current_group.text:
                     current_group = SubElement(description, 'hole',{'hole_id':"%s"%i})

                     information = SubElement (current_group, 'hole',{'collar':x1 + y1 + z1,
                                                              'toe':x2 + y2 + z2,
                                                              'cost':cost})
             i+=1

   tree.write(open('holes.xml','w'))
```

Comment: please post the code that you used to generate this

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
{'collar':x1 + y1 + z1,
 'toe':x2 + y2 + z2,
 'cost':cost}
```

Use:

```
{'collar': ', '.join([x1, y1, z1]),
 'toe':    ', '.join([x2, y2, z2]),
 'cost':   cost}
```

Or:

```
{'collar': '%s, %s, %s' % (x1, y1, z1),
 'toe':    '%s, %s, %s' % (x2, y2, z2),
 'cost':   cost}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instad of

```
'collar':x1 + y1 + z1,
```

write

```
'collar': ", "join((x1, y1, z1))
```